# Why is my HelloWorld function not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, scope

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;
}

void HelloWorld()
{
    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}
```

I am getting the following compilation error with g++:

```
l1.cpp: In function 'int main()':
l1.cpp:5:15: error: 'HelloWorld' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: I love how this question shot straight up the StackExchange as a "Hot Question."

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why prototype is required even without any class declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199081/why-prototype-is-required-even-without-any-class-declaration)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You need to either declare or define the function before you can use it. Otherwise, it doesn't know that `HelloWorld()` exists as a function.

Add this before your main function:

```
void HelloWorld();
```

Alternatively, you can move the definition of `HelloWorld()` before your `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void HelloWorld()
{
  cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  HelloWorld();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You must declare the function before you can use it:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void HelloWorld();

int main()
{
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;
}

void HelloWorld()
{
    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}
```

or you can move the definition of `HelloWorld()` before `main()`

Comment: but you can use a class member before you declare it. So this explanation is not satisfying.

Comment: @Walter My explanation covers specifically his problem, and since he's new, there is no point flooding him with so much information.

Answer (score 17):

You need to forward declare `HelloWorld()` so `main` knows what it is. Like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void HelloWorld();
int main()
{
  HelloWorld();
  return 0;
}
void HelloWorld()
{
  cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

There is one more possibility for some reason nobody mentioned, namely using extern declaration:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  extern void HelloWorld();
  HelloWorld();
  return 0;
}
void HelloWorld()
{
  cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}
```

It's preferable when you don't want to introduce name of the function into namespace scope.

Answer (score 10):

You need to have either a prototype of the function before the invocation or the whole function before it.

So the first is:

```
void HelloWorld();

int main() {
  HelloWorld();
  return 0;
}

void HelloWorld() {
  cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}
```

And the second way is:

```
void HelloWorld() {
  cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}

int main() {
  HelloWorld();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

All these answers are correct, but strangely enough, this would have worked:

```
struct Hello {
  static int main() { World(); return 0; } /* note: World() not declared yet */
  static void World() { std::cout<<"Hello World"; }
};
int main() { return Hello::main(); }
```

Comment: There is nothing strange, all members of the class are already defined inside the body of member functions.

Comment: @Gene It's not immediately obvious (to a beginner/outsider anyway) why in `namespace X { int a() { return b;} int b; }` we have a problem, but not if we replace `namespace` by `class` (and add `;` at the end).

Answer (score 4):

You have to put the function before the main function.

Answer (score 3):

in C++ you need to define or at least declare the functions before calling them.

What you are trying to do till now is something like this :

```
int main()
{
   cout << b;
   int b = 10;
}
```

So you can also trying like this :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;  

void HelloWorld();

int main()  
{
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;  
}
void HelloWorld()
{
  cout << "Hello, World" << endl;  
}
```

It is a good practice in C++ to define all other functions before the main function.

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange `HelloWorld()` so that it appears before `main()`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void HelloWorld()
{
    cout << "Hello, World" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're defining you're functioning below your main function you should declare it above first.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void HelloWorld();
int main()  
{
    HelloWorld();
    return 0;  
}
void HelloWorld()
{
  cout << "Hello, World" << endl;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `void HelloWorld()` above `main()` method or add function prototype `void HelloWorld();` so compiler can compile it . if the prototyped function does not exist then you get a linker error.
in this case
you are trying like this

```
  std::cout <<hello<<endl;
  std::string hello = "hello world";
```