# A question about dice probability and 2D array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, probability, dice

Find out the probability of different total values when several unbiased dices were thrown at the same time. The program makes use of various techniques including basic I/O, arithmetic, conditional control structures, loops and arrays.

Visit https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gf10Pi_ME2jpmMM4_Y62-gkZ3we_llyy/view?usp=sharing for the details of information.

I am using the 2d array to finish the work. However, it was not okay to go on as it outputted the problem of "out of the scope".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Initialise the variables
    int number;
    cout << "Input the number of dice(s): ";
    cin >> number;

    //Initialise 2d array and set number as the row
    int face[20][20];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        cin >> face[i + 1][20];
    }

    //Initialise 2d array and set input value as the column
    int value;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        //Consider the output statement of the number of faces for dice
        switch (number + 1) {
        case 1:
            cout << "Input the number of the faces for the " << number + 1 << "st" << " dice: ";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Input the number of the faces for the " << number + 1 << "nd" << " dice: ";
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Input the number of the faces for the " << number + 1 << "rd" << " dice: ";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Input the number of the faces for the " << number + 1 << "th" << " dice: ";
        }
        cin >> face[i][value];
    }
    //calculate the sum of the dice
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        sum = sum + face[i][value];
    }

    //initialise the base value (max probability) of the dice
    int base;
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        base = base * face[i][value];
    }

    //Output statement
    if (number < 10) {
        for (int i = number; i < sum; i++) {
            cout << "Probability of " << i << " = " << probability(i, base, face);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = number; i < 10; i++) {
            cout << "Probability of  " << i << " = " << probability(i, base, face);
        }
        for (int i = 10; i < sum; i++) {
            cout << "Probability of  " << i << " = " << probability(i, base, face);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

//Calculating the probability
int probability(int number, int base, int face[20][20])
{
    int probability = 0;
    int rollresult = face[0][0];
    while (rollresult == number) {
        for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j; j++) {
                rollresult = face[i][j] + rollresult;
            }
        }
        probability++;
    }
    return probability;
}
```

error messages:

```
In function 'int main()':
51:69: error: 'probability' was not declared in this scope
56:70: error: 'probability' was not declared in this scope
59:70: error: 'probability' was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Read about [scopes in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope)

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234484/why-is-my-helloworld-function-not-declared-in-this-scope

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to call the `probability()` function before you have declared it! You can keep the actual definition after `main` but you will then need to put a 'forward' declaration of it earlier on. Try inserting a declaration, immediately before 'main`, thus:

```
int probability(int number, int base, int face[20][20]);

int main() {
    ...
```