# How to call a function in main/ experimenting with CPP

Tags: c++

I'm experimenting with C++ currently, and i'm wondering how I'm able to call fun1 noted below in main:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Result is: " << fun1(1, 4, 1)();
}

int fun1(int x, int y, int z) {
some stuff
}
```

I get an error on main at fun1 here:

```
 clang++-7 -pthread -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
main.cpp:4:33: error: use of undeclared identifier 'fun1'
  std::cout << "Result is: " << fun1(1, 4, 1)();
                                ^
1 error generated.
compiler exit status 1

```

Can someone help out with how to call fun1, thanks.

Comment: remove the () should just be fun1(1,4,1). and also you need to have the function declaration above main

Comment: @OmidCompSCI that still results in error at fun1. hmm

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my HelloWorld function not declared in this scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234484/why-is-my-helloworld-function-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the() from the call and it should be fun1(1,4,1). You also need to declare the function above main, or move the whole function above main including implementation

```
#include <iostream>
int fun1(int x, int y, int z);

int main() {
  std::cout << "Result is: " << fun1(1, 4, 1);
}

int fun1(int x, int y, int z) {
some stuff
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
int fun1(int x, int y, int z) {
some stuff
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Result is: " << fun1(1, 4, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare functions before use.

And also remove extra `()` as @OmidCompSCI says.

```
#include <iostream>

int fun1(int x, int y, int z); // add this

int main() {
  std::cout << "Result is: " << fun1(1, 4, 1);
}

int fun1(int x, int y, int z) {
some stuff
}
```