# Calling Method/Function outside a Class but on the same namespace in c++/cli

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have a very simple and yet complicated (atleast for me) question on how to call a method/function outside a class but on a same namespace in c++/cli.

I know that you need to create an instance of an object before you can call a method which is inside a class, something like:

```
namespace Cars {
    
    public ref class MyClass
    {
       void Honda(int i)
       {
          //some code
       }
    }
    
    void Register()
    {
        MyClass c;
        c.Honda(1);
    
        //some code
    
    }
}
```

But how do I do the opposite? Like how do I call `Register()` inside the `MyClass::Honda` function if they are on the same namespace but not on the same class?

I tried `Cars::Register()` but it gives an error saying that:

> Register() is not a member of "Cars".

Edit: I added the actual code that I tried to access the `Register()` method.

```
namespace Cars {
    
    public ref class MyClass
    {
        void Honda(int i)
        {
            Cars::Register();
        }
    }
    
    void Register()
    {
        //some code
    }
    
}
```

The line `Cars::Register()`; do not give any error when I save but when I try to rebuild my application it gives the error below:

> Error  C2039   'Register': is not a member of 'Cars'
>
> Error  C3861   'Register': identifier not found

Just to note that when I put `Register()` inside the `MyClass`, everything works well (for some reason I just need to put it outside the class)

Thanks!

Comment: Move the definition of `Register` before that of `MyClass`. Or at least forward-declare `Register` before it's called. In C++, all names must be declared before they can be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Why is my HelloWorld function not declared in this scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234484/why-is-my-helloworld-function-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**There are 2 issues in your code:**

1. Missing `;` at the end of the definition for `ref class MyClass`.
2. `Register()` should be defined (or at least declared) before calling it.

**Fixed version:**

```
namespace Cars 
{
    // Defintion:
    void Register()
    {
        //some code
    }

    public ref class MyClass
    {
        void Honda(int i)
        {
            Cars::Register();
        }
    };
}
```

**Or alternatively:**

```
namespace Cars 
{
    // Declaration:
    void Register();
        
    public ref class MyClass
    {
        void Honda(int i)
        {
            Cars::Register();
        }
    };

    // Definition:
    void Register()
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

**Note:** since you call `Register` within the same namespace, you can actually drop the `Cars::` qualifier, i.e. simply call: `Register();`. You also keep it of course, if you think it improves readability.