# What is Wrong with my Code in calling function in main?

Tags: c++, function, debugging

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> big_vector = {5,12,4,6,7,8,9,9,31,1,1,5,76,78,8};

    vector<int> a = sub(big_vector);
    cout<<a.size();
    return 0;

}
vector<int> sub(vector<int> big_vector){

    return {big_vector.begin() + 7, big_vector.end() - 2};
}
```

I get this error and do not know why
main.cpp:18:21: error: ‘sub’ was not declared in this scope

debugging and running different test

Comment: You need to declare `sub` before using it, e.g. add `vector<int> sub(vector<int> big_vector);` before `main()`.

Comment: Because `sub` has to at least be *declared* before `main` is *defined*.

Comment: BTW, you have a potential UB with your iterators there: Make sure to check that `big_vector` has at least 9 elements before doing it like that.

Comment: Order or declarations/definitions in C++ matter, a compiler reads the code from the top to the bottom.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my HelloWorld function not declared in this scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234484/why-is-my-helloworld-function-not-declared-in-this-scope)

Answer (score 2):

In C++ all objects must be ***declared*** before they are used.

```
    vector<int> a = sub(big_vector);
```

Your reliable compiler reads this, and it has absolutely no clue, whatsoever, what this mysterious `sub` function is all about.

Human eyeballs that are owned by a carbon-based life form can easily see this function, later in the file. But your compiler is a beast of logic. It hasn't read that far ahead, into the source file. That's why, in C++, in this situation the function must be ***declared***:

```
vector<int> sub(vector<int>);
```

Put this ***before*** the `main` function. The compiler reads this first, and learns all about this amazing function called `sub()`, which has one `vector<int>` parameter, and returns a `vector<int>` itself. So when it reads the contents of `main()`, which calls this function, it knows exactly what it's all about, and can proceed further.

Or, you can simply put the entire `sub()` function ***before*** the `main()` function. That'll work, too.

Comment: I always thought it very strange that C programmers traditionally put all their functions _after_ the functions that use them.

Comment: @Dúthomhas I'm with you. It's not so bad if you have a tool that parses the code and automates the generation of the forward declarations, but maintaining forward declarations by hand is a nuisance I'd rather avoid and an ready source of unforced errors.