# Problem With Functions And Printing Function Values in arduino

Tags: c++, function, arduino

First of all, I'm gonna say thank you to who help me 
so recently I was working on a project which is called Green House in Arduino
then I was about to write a function that reads sensor, and a function that prints that value in function1 and I just came up with some problems, 
Here is My code
First of all, I just defined every pin and then 
written functions
and this is functions and the main code which has problems

```
void GetState();

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
GetState();
PrintState();
delay(2000);
}
void PrintState()
{
Serial.println("TEMP ");
Serial.println(temp);
Serial.println("Rotobate Khak");
Serial.println(soilstate);
Serial.println("Humidity");
Serial.println(hum);
Serial.println("LDR === ");
Serial.println(LDRSTATE);
Serial.print("\n");
}
void GetState()
{
DHT.read11(Sensor);
int LDRSTATE=analogRead(LDR);
return LDRSTATE;
 int soilstate=analogRead(soil);
soilstate= map(soilstate,0,1023,100.00,0);  
return soilstate;
int temp=DHT.temperature;
return temp;
 int hum=DHT.humidity;
return hum;
}
```

```
and I get 'temp' was not declared in this scope error
```

Comment: When asking a question, Please post the code in the question itself.  Do not post links as they can disappear

Comment: Decide which programming language They cannot be a mix of those three languages. Pick one that matches the actual code then remove the 'tags' for other languages

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8199081/why-prototype-is-required-even-without-any-class-declaration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare "int temp;" at the top. The same for all other variables. Do not declare the variables in GetState, just use them.
Remove all "return" lines from Getstate(). Just setting "temp=DHT.temperature;" sets the variable and is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `GetState()` function *before* `loop()` (where it is called).  Or, if you prefer, you can add a prototype before `loop()`:

```
void GetState();

void loop() {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you are quite new to programming. Please try giving prototypes of `GetState()` and `PrintState()` functions above their definition. This is because C/C++ compiler assumes that it returns `int` by default if there isn't any prototype.
Otherwise, you can create a header file and then include that header file in this program.

Comment: thank you-you mean that I have to do that ?`temp = GetState(temp)`? and then i print it ?

Comment: after that I've got the A`A function definition is not allowed here before ‘}’ token` error before `PrintState()`

Comment: Please go through this fully https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/. It'll help you get a clearer idea on how to write C code. Your GetState() function is incorrect. You can return only one variable and you've declared your function to be of void return type. Accept additional parameters as pointers and write to those variables instead of doing like this.